# Material ui + react Trying to create a Horizontal list of cards but not cant scroll them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

First of all, thanks for helping!!
I am trying to create an scrollable list of cards in my react page using Material ui, but I am not able to make the list scrollable. How could I create a list of scrollable cards.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzZKe.png)

This is my code:

```
return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex',flexWrap: 'wrap',justifyContent: 'space-around',overflow: 'hidden',width: 1200 }}>
        <Grid container spacing={3} style={{flexWrap: 'nowrap'}}>
          {data.map((data, index) => {
            const { Title, Summary } = data;
            return (
              <Grid item>
                <Card sx={{ width:300 }}>
                  <CardMedia
                    sx={{ height: 140 }}
                    image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
                    title="green iguana"
                  />
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                      {Title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                      {Summary}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            );
          })}
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Please create a sandbox link so that we can help out. Try adding overflowX:"scroll". That should work if you want to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Thanks you @arp that solved my problem!!
Do you know if i can make that the sides of the list is blurred?